# Image Mean Normalization

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, normalization, mean

I am wondering if I understood the mean normalization of images correctly.

As far as I know, you calculate the mean value over all pixels (lets assume it is in grayscale). Then, for each pixel, you subtract this mean value.

But how should one deal with negative values which could arise? For example, the whole image has a mean value of 100, but one specific pixel has an intensity of 90. After this normalization, the pixel's value would be -10.

Comment: and what's wrong with that? after mean normalization some feature will be negative of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be quite what you're looking for but one option that avoids negative numbers in your output would be to normalize to the range of values present rather than to the image mean. 
The equation would be: X' = (X - Xmin)/(Xmax - Xmin). This rescales the image to be between 0 and 1 (no negative values involved). If you'd like to save it as an easily view-able greyscale you could multiply values by 255 to rescale it.

It may also be worth noting that unless the entire image has a constant intensity, there is guaranteed to be some negative values after subtracting the mean (not simply a possibility that they could arise).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to deal with negative inputs, the model can handle them. It is good practice, for a Neural Network for example, to have inputs in the range [-1, 1]